# Why is my data being displayed as null when trying to pass it from my activity to fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to pass information from my activity to my fragment but i am having some issues. I followed the steps as directed on stackoverflow from previous user's post. But my data is not being displayed. Can someone tell me why i am having this issue?

**This is the code inside my activity**

```
  PennyStocksFragment fragment = new PennyStocksFragment();
  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
  bundle.putString("SELECTEDSTRINGSECTOR", "something"); // Put anything what you want
  fragment.setArguments(bundle);
  FragmentManager fm = ((FilterActivity.this).getSupportFragmentManager());
  FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
  ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
  ft.commit();
```

**This is how I attempt to retrieve it inside my fragment**

```
String data = this.getArguments().getString("SELECTEDSTRINGSECTOR");
Log.i("tickerSymbolVar",data);
```

Comment: At which point in fragment you are trying to access the arguments ?

Comment: I placed it inside my onCreateView of my fragment

Comment: Can you paste your Logcat view where you are verifying the data ?

Answer (score 0):

This method will work when you have one `Activity`. I think you are getting data from another activity fragment? If I am correct, then first go to that activity and on activity pass data to a fragment and then get it here

Comment: I have one activity, i am trying to send data from that activity to a fragment

Answer (score 0):

simple pass data to the fragment's parameter like this and access it in fragment class in constructor:

```
PennyStocksFragment fragment = new PennyStocksFragment("your data");
bundle.putString("SELECTEDSTRINGSECTOR", "something"); 

FragmentManager fm = ((FilterActivity.this).getSupportFragmentManager());
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
  ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
  ft.commit();
```

and access it in fragment's constructor:

```
public PennyStocksFragment(String s){
String data = s;
}
```